# FlexBe Unable to import temporary behavior file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Behavior)

when i run the behaviour i get this error

> Unable to import temporary behavior file:
> No module named src.flexbe_states.log_state

I have set up a home directory as per the instructions, when i compared the file i created following the tutorial  to the installed example

this is my result

```
from flexbe_states.src.flexbe_states.log_state import LogState
from flexbe_states.src.flexbe_states.wait_state import WaitState
```

this is from the installed example

```
from flexbe_states.log_state import LogState
from flexbe_states.wait_state import WaitState
```

when edit my file it this it works but as soon as i edit my behaviour it goes back.

i have configured states to
`~/catkin_ws/src/flexbe_behavior_engine/flexbe_states`
Im running

Ubuntu 14.4 64 bit

ROS indigo installed from debs

on a ASUS k53s I7  with 8 gis of ram
on a fresh install and update

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220077/flexbe-unable-to-import-temporary-behavior-file/) by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

this results from the FlexBE App configuration. As you wrote, you added `~/catkin_ws/src/flexbe_behavior_engine/flexbe_states` to the "State Library" panel.

Correct would be in this case: `~/catkin_ws/src/flexbe_behavior_engine/flexbe_states/src/flexbe_states`
(see installation guidelines on the homepage: "Make sure to add the folder which contains the states, not the ROS package itself (i.e. ... /flexbe_behavior_engine/flexbe_states/src/flexbe_states)".

I guess I need to make it more obvious, sorry! Or just make it also work this way. Just ask if there are further problems and thank you for trying FlexBE. :)

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2015-10-29**:
Thank you for the quick response it works now

**Comment by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) on 2015-10-29**:
I just pushed an update. Your first configuration would now work as well and even simply passing `~/catkin_ws/src` in order to use all states inside your workspace is possible.